# Coverage of powershell script using Pester

Tags: node.js, powershell, pester

I am trying to unit test my Powershell script file with below code snippet using Pester

```
#code to create a 7z file 
$7zipPath = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"
Set-Alias 7zip $7zipPath
if (!(Test-Path -Path $7zipPath -PathType Leaf)) {
    throw "7 zip file '$7zipPath' not found"
}
7zip a -mx=9 $jenkinsWorkspacepath\IntegrationZip.7z $jenkinsWorkspacepath\IntegratedScripts
```

And mocking the Test-Path command as below

```
    Mock -CommandName Test-Path –MockWith {
        Return $false  
    }
```

But the coverage report shows the below line as uncovered.. What am i doing wrong here(in the mocking part)?

```
**throw "7 zip file '$7zipPath' not found"**
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your test look like?  I tried the following and it worked fine for your code:

```
Mock -CommandName Test-Path -MockWith { return $false }  

It "fails to find executable" {
    { Invoke-SevenZip } | Should -Throw "not found"
}
```

**Note**: I wrapped your code in a function called `Invoke-SevenZip`

Comment: This is likely the answer. You need to have a test that is checking for a `Throw` result. You pipe a scriptblock to the test for `-Throw` as Boxdog has shown above.